# Cohen d for mixed effects model

Tags: r, mixed-models

has anyone worked with the **powerlmm** package?
I want to calculate statistical power for my model with the study_parameters command. It takes multiple values as input one of which is Cohen's d.

How do I figure out what is the Cohen d for my model? Also, for which effects exactly should I specify cohen d: for fixed, random or for the entire model?

```
p <- study_parameters(n1 = 6,
                      n2 = per_treatment(control=27, treatment=55),
                      sigma_subject_intercept = 4.56,
                      sigma_subject_slope = 0.22,
                      sigma_error = 5.39,
                      cor_subject = -0.19,
                      dropout = dropout_manual(0.0000000, 0.2666667, 0.3466667, 0.4666667, 0.47, 0.7333333),
                      effect_size = cohend(0.5), 
                                           standardizer = "posttest_SD"))
get_power(p)
```

Some details about the study:

- 2 groups: Treatment and Control
- 6 Timepoints
- n(control)=27, n(treatment)=55

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You get Cohens d from the output of the function. I see you made a small error in your code. Delete the "`)`", after `cohend(.05` and it works.
- By definition, you are interested in the effect size of the fixed effect.

Hope it works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Point 2 is ok. Case closed. As for point 1, it's not exactly what I meant. I'll put it in another way. As I understand, when I specify cohen d, it's like I am asking "What is the power for my model with a cohen d of 0.5". But I didn't calculate cohen d as there are now recomandations for this in the documentation for the package. How to calculate cohen d for a mixed model? Or, is it more of an arbitrary selection in this case? Like asking "What is the power if the model had a cohen d of 0.5?".

Comment: Aha. I did not really understand the question. You know how to calculate power with `powerlmm` but not how to obtain an effect size from a multilevel model? If thats the case then you should be aware that there is, as far as i am aware, no agreed upon definition on how to do this. See link below. 

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410812/cohens-d-from-mixed-method-model-for-the-interaction-term